# How can I toggle a boolean number?

Tags: php, function, numbers

Here is my code:

```
$num = 1; // it always is either 0 or 1

if ( $num == 1 ){
    $num = 0
} else {
    $num = 1;
}
```

As you see, my code toggles the number. It is really ugly to me. I guessed php should has a function to do so. But I didn't find anything similar after some searches. Anyway, can I do that more standard and better?

<sub>Currectly I'm coding for a great company. That's why I want to write clean and professional codes.</sub>

Comment: Boolean number? Why not use an actual boolean - `true` / `false`..

Comment: Why don't you simply use `!`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your approach is correct and will work as well. Just you need to wrap it into a function. Another way is using [`^ (Bitwise XOR)`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) to do that functional and more clean:

```
function toggleNumber( $num ) {
    return $num ^= 1;
}
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/h7TAe)

---

That function gets the number and does XOR with `1` on it. Then the number will be toggled.

Answer (score 7):

All Mothods below only use 1 line of code

Method 1) use `!` operator

```
<?php 

$num = 1;

$num = (int) !$num;   // method 1
```

Method 2) use array to return with num as index

```
<?php 

  $num =1;

  $num = array(1,0)[$num];  //method 2
```

Method 3) use conditional operator

```
<?php 

  $num =1;

  $num = (int) ($num < 1);  // if 1 return 0 else return 1 , method 3
```

Method 4) Hack using empty function

```
<?php 

  $num = 1;

  $num = (int)empty($num);  // method 4
```

> [Oneline Demo](https://3v4l.org/XVpHJ)

Comment: Methods 2, 3 or 4 do not propose a toggle on the value. So you're not answering the question.

Comment: edited my answer. check it  . in previous edits i tried to display it. Now if the value of num is 1 it changes to 0 and viceversa

Comment: here is the function implementation of all the above https://3v4l.org/jkpRp . also here is the demo https://3v4l.org/lCvf3 of edited code .might contain echo just delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple of fun ways, if number is 1 return 0 or 1

```
$num = 1;
function toggle1($num){
   if($num){
      return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

without argument, just toggle away for flip flop action

```
function toggle2(){
    static $num = 1;
    $num = ($num?0:1);
    return $num;
}
```

with argument

```
function toggle3($num){
    return ($num?0:1);
}
```

like @B. Desai but cast to int

```
function toggle4($num){
    return (int) !$num;
}
```

straight up like the example but ternary

```
$num = 1;
$num = ($num?0:1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `!` operator to toggle number between `0` and `1`;

```
$num = 1; // it always is either 0 or 1
function toggleNumber($num)
{
  return !$num;
}
$num = intval(toggleNumber($num));
echo $num; //print 0
echo "<br>";
$num = intval(toggleNumber($num));
echo $num; // print 1
```

You can directly use `$num = intval(!($num));` to toggle number. But function is good approach.

Answer (score 2):

Simple subtraction.  Just subtract the current value from 1.  This will not perform as quickly as bitwise, but it will be easily comprehensible by other coders if you are working in a team.  The performance differences will be measurable in nanoseconds.  `$num=1-$num` is a single line expression that doesn't use a conditional statement.

```
$num=1;

echo $num=1-$num,"\n";  // 0
echo $num=1-$num,"\n";  // 1
echo $num=1-$num;       // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're coding for a great company, you don't want to use a number that will act as a boolean.

If you know for sure that your number will always be 0 or 1, then use a [Boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). Here are some reason:

- In a few days/monthes/years, you will have to run through this code again, and you will see a number, so maybe you'll forget about that 0/1 rule that you implicitly set.
- If somebody else read through your code, how is he going to know that this can only be 0/1 ?
- When you (or someone else) will write documentation about that, do you really want to put in: "This is a number that can be only 0 or 1" ?

If you happend to use a boolean, that toggle thing you ask is much more easy:

```
$value = TRUE; //TRUE is a PHP Constant

$value = !$value; //Toggled, $value is now equal to FALSE

if ($value) { } //instead of if ($num == 1)
if (!$value) { } //instead of if ($num == 0)
```

In the documentation, you can state that this is a boolean value, everybody understands there are only two possibilities: TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

> **In one line you can do it**
>
> ```
> $num = 1;
> echo ($num == 1) ? 0 : 1;
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it would be:

```
$num = 1 - $num;
```

Comment: The more clean version would be `$num -= 1;`

Comment: Actually, no

In that case, if num was initially 0, it would become 0 - 1 = (-1) afterwards.

That wouldn't work

Comment: Kindly remove this late duplicate of my earlier posted answer and regain your lost rep points.