# Why doesn't my decrementing while loop break?

Tags: php, while-loop, break, decrement

I have got this code.
I am using break, but loop is not stopping.

```
$Hero = array(
        'atak'  => 100,
        'zycie' => 1000
    );
$Potwor = array(
        'atak'  => 100,
        'zycie' => 500
    );

$BattleLog = array();
while(true) {
    $kogo_ruch = rand(1, 2);
    if($kogo_ruch == 1) {
        $Hero['atak'] -= $Potwor['zycie'];
    }else{
        $Potwor['atak'] -= $Hero['zycie'];
    }

    if($Potwor['zycie'] <= 0){
        break;
    }elseif($Hero['zycie'] <=0 ){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: please paste the code in the question, not on some 3rd party website.

Comment: Those numbers in your break condition don't change. They stays the same and therefore it will never break from loop.

Comment: thanks, but why this values dont changes? i am using " .= "

Comment: You are not doing anything to those keys. You only decrement 'atack' key by their amount.

Comment: `$Hero['zycie']` and `$Potwor['zycie']` are never modified in your code. Can't expect to break the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to miss this chance to show you some more advanced techniques that will simplify your code block and eliminate some if statements.

By packaging your two combatants into a single "fighters" array where the first fighter (Hero) is element `[0]` and the monster (Potwor) is element `[1]`, you can refer to each using simple arithmetic.

As far as your original code, it doesn't make sense to write `break`s at the end of your loop.  The correct placement for your conditions is directly in your while statement as enpaul mentioned.

Notice that I have changed the `rand()` range from `1-2` to `0-1` for simple toggling between the two values in the damage calculation line.

To target the opponent in each round, I am using `1-$losowy`.  I find this to be the most intuitive/elementary way to toggle the value.  However, there are other techniques including [a method that uses a bitwise operator (it is the fastest performing way to do it, but the least intuitive)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44608171/2943403).

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9318450e8220a8cfa64a4736f1036578d302efdd))

```
$Wojownicy=[
    ['zycie'=>1000,'atak'=>100],  // Bohater(Hero) : life points , attack points
    ['zycie'=>500,'atak'=>100]    // Potwor(Monster) : life points , attack points
];

while($Wojownicy[0]['zycie']>0 && $Wojownicy[1]['zycie']>0){
    $losowy=rand(0,1);  // identify attacker
    $Wojownicy[1-$losowy]['zycie']-=$Wojownicy[$losowy]['atak'];  // subract attack from opponent
    echo "Hero={$Wojownicy[0]['zycie']} -vs- Monster={$Wojownicy[1]['zycie']}\n";  // display each round
}
// Spoiler Alert: The Hero wins almost every time!
```

An Unlikely Result:

```
Hero=900 -vs- Monster=500
Hero=900 -vs- Monster=400
Hero=800 -vs- Monster=400
Hero=700 -vs- Monster=400
Hero=600 -vs- Monster=400
Hero=500 -vs- Monster=400
Hero=400 -vs- Monster=400
Hero=300 -vs- Monster=400
Hero=200 -vs- Monster=400
Hero=100 -vs- Monster=400
Hero=100 -vs- Monster=300
Hero=100 -vs- Monster=200
Hero=100 -vs- Monster=100
Hero=0 -vs- Monster=100
```

Answer (score 0):

You never modify the value of either array value that you're using to trigger the break. You set the two `zycie` indexes to static values but without modifying those values, they will never meet your loop exit conditions.

I'm not exactly sure what behavior/rules you need to express, but this code would exit successfully:

```
while(true) {
  $kogo_ruch = rand(1, 2);

  if($kogo_ruch == 1) {
    $Potwor['zycie'] -= $Hero['atak'];
  }
  else {
    $Hero['zycie'] -= $Potwor['atak'];
  }

  if($Potwor['zycie'] <= 0) {
    break;
  } 
  else if($Hero['zycie'] <=0 ) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Also, just as a general note, its generally not a good idea to use a `while(true)` loop unless its absolutely necessary. I'd recommend doing something like this instead:

```
while($Potwor['zycie'] > 0 && $Hero['zycie'] > 0) {
  // Loop stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are updating element `atak` in both array and put break on other element `zycie` as you already run you loop infinite with `while(true)` I think you need to put break on element `atak` like below

```
if($Potwor['atak'] <= 0) {
  break;
}
else if($Hero['atak'] <=0 ) {
  break;
}
```

Or check your logic carefully.